# Does null in a character array prevent memory being deleted beyond it?

Tags: c++

Is there any memory leak ?

```
    const char * pname = "NAME";
    char * temp = new char[strlen(Name) + 64];
    sprintf(temp,"%s", pname);

    delete [] temp; // is there any memory leaks because now length of temp is 4.
```

Comment: don't `delete[]` `pname` as you are initializing it statically using string literal.

Comment: Your question seems to be: 'does null affect how much memory is deleted when deleting a character string?'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No there won't be any memory leak. `sprintf` will only use the bytes of `temp` that it requires, BUT, all of the bytes initially created will remain allocated (even though some are unused).

The call to `delete[] temp` will then deallocate *all* the bytes originally allocated.

As others have pointed out though, do not free `pname`. You should only call `delete` and `delete[]` on pointers which were created with `new` and `new[]` respectively.

**Additional information:**

When you created `temp`, `new[]` allocated an array of contiguous bytes in memory PLUS an additional (small) space where it stores the information about the allocation (how large the allocation is, for instance). When you called `delete[]` it examined that information and found that `strlen(Name)+64` bytes were allocated, and so it knows it has to deallocate all of them. The fact that you only used a small fraction of the allocated space does not make a difference.

Answer (score 6):

It is undefined behavior to delete(modify) string literal(`pname`). 
Also `new/delete`, `new []/delete[]` are only used in pair.

Suggest use `std::string` if you could, let `std::string` manage the memory allocation/deallocation for you.

```
  std::string pname("NAME");
  std::string temp(pname);
  std::cout << pname << std::endl;
```

Answer (score 4):

No, no matter where the trailing 0 of temp is the allocated memory for it is still the initial `strlen(Name) + 64` so the delete frees the whole block of memory which is correct.

As @billz pointed out you should not free pname.